# How to lazy load the jaxws client

Tags: jax-ws

The WSDL and client code generated using wsimport are very big. So want a way / setting in jaxws to load only necessary client classes instead of loading all of them which takes ~10 secs and heap consumed is also huge.
Also on creating multiple ports using different 10 threads the memory used is easily going up to 1.5G and getting out of memory error.

It will be of great help if I can get to load the client stub objects lazily.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be fixed the way you expect. Java loads classes in a lazy manner anyway, it doesn't act differently with JAX-WS and it's not acting strangely in your specific case. There's no setting in JAX-WS to change something and solve your problem.

It seems to me that your real problem is a HUGE web service with myriads of methods, parameters, faults, etc, although I tend to believe your heap usage and out-of-memory conditions should be attributed to the rest of the application and not to the JAX-WS client.

I think your solution is in the direction of breaking-up your one, huge web service into multiple web services, partitioned by functionality or some other concept. Then, you would only be using the services (and their clients) that you really need.

Comment: Thanks vagelis, Here the issue is not about class loading, it's about the portType which loads completely for each thread adds up to a big heap. Yes it's a bug service and when using axis2 we didn't had this issue as it was loading the portType objects only when required. Now looking for a way to not to load all the objects upfront in JAXWS client.

Comment: It is just the way the JAX-WS service proxy is structured: too many interconnected classes. What if you compare the class counts for JAX-WS and Axis?

Comment: Class count may be same for both but it's a concern, main concern is the multiple portTypes which are required (they are not thread safe) and they take up lot of heap ~1gb for say  for 10 threads. So running with 50 threads will need ~5gb heap which is not acceptable :-(